# Function throws error when trying to run a second time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a problem with a download button. If I reload the page, the onClick={() => ExportAll(data)} works fine the first time when pressing the download button, however when I try it after that the console throws this error:
[image: screenshot of the error]

The function itself looks like this:

```
const exportAll = (data) => {
    const arr = []
      data.map((element) => {
            element.orderlines = element?.orderlines?.join(' , ')
            arr.push(element)
          }
      );
      exportFileAsXLSX(arr, `Meest recente orders-${props.timespan}`);
  };
```

The data object is set using the useState hook

If anyone has any idea why this doesn't work, please let me know!

Comment: What is `element.orderlines` when it errors?

Comment: let me check real quick

Comment: you're mutating the `orderlines`  array into a string, what did you expect ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const exportAll = (data) => {
    const arr = []
      data.map((element) => {
            let newElement = { ...element}
            newElement.orderlines = element?.orderlines?.join(' , ')
            arr.push(newElement)
          }
      );
      exportFileAsXLSX(arr, `Meest recente orders-${props.timespan}`);
  };
```

At first execution you overwrite original objects orderlines field value. Then at the next time you try to apply join operation to that field value again. Now it is a string not an array. That is the reason for the error.Change the code as above it will work.Above code I create a new obj rather than overwriting it.

Comment: You're not deep-copying the arrays here.

Comment: Earlier my description has a issue. I update it. Thanks @Matthieu Riegler.

Answer (score 0):

Is orderlines an array? Cause you can only use join() if it is indeed an array!

Double check if it's not an object.